# How to merge two nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to merge using this way but it making two different keys of `meta_information` and `meta_information.image`

```
merchant = Object.assign(merchant, media_mode)
```

I have tried this way but its not working

```
var media_mode = {
    "featured_media_square" : "square",
    "featured_media_landscape" :"landscape",
    "logo" : "a.png",
    "meta_information.image" : "b.png"  
}

var merchant = {meta_information : {image : ""}}
```

I want to get result like this

```
merchant = {
    "featured_media_square" : "square",
     "featured_media_landscape" : "landscape",
     "logo" : "a.png",
     "meta_information" : {"image" : "b.png"}  
}
```

Comment: @ngfelixl its not working , its not giving the response i mentioned above

Comment: You're getting a lot of unhelpful answers. I would recommend first modifying your first object to match the format of the second before performing your nested merge. I.e. transform the dot notation in the keys to proper nested objects. Then you can use existing strategies for a deep merge.

Comment: for some reason Iam getting downwoted, yet its the only answer that produces the model you asked for, before it gets lots, you cant merge them, you have to remap the value. "meta_information.image" cant be easily transformed to a object path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They cant merge, you would have to remap them manually, for instance desctructure media_mode, and pull "image" out of it and then having rest of the object as "...rest", then just put that together in the exact model you asked for

```js
var media_mode = {
  featured_media_square: "square",
  featured_media_landscape: "landscape",
  logo: "a.png",
  "meta_information.image": "b.png",
};

var { "meta_information.image": image, ...rest } = media_mode;

merchant = {
  ...rest,
  meta_information: { image },
};

console.log(merchant);
```

ES5 as requested

```js
var media_mode = {
  featured_media_square: "square",
  featured_media_landscape: "landscape",
  logo: "a.png",
  "meta_information.image": "b.png",
};

const image = media_mode["meta_information.image"];

var merchant = Object.assign({}, media_mode, {
  meta_information: { image: image },
});

console.log(merchant);
```

note that in this solution key "meta_information.image" remains in the result, if you would insists on removing it, just run

```
delete merchant["meta_information.image"]
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do it in es5 syntax

Comment: @YashGandhi there you go ES5, not as elegant but should work

Answer (score 4):

```js
var media_mode = {
  "featured_media_square" : "square",
  "featured_media_landscape":"landscape",
  "logo":"a.png",
  "meta_information.image":"b.png"  
}

var merchant = {meta_information:{image:""}};
  
for (var key in media_mode) {
     var kn = key.split(".");
     for (var key2 in merchant) {
    if (kn[0] === key2) {
     var tmp = media_mode[key];
        media_mode[kn[0]] = {};
     media_mode[kn[0]][kn[1]] = tmp;
        delete media_mode[key]
    }
  }
}
  
console.log(media_mode);
```

ECMA5 version.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to merge using this way but it making two different keys of meta_information and meta_information.image

Because they **are** two different keys.

`meta_information` and `meta_information.image` won't merge/override unless the keys match with `===`.

What you're asking is not available right out of the box in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var media_mode = {
  "featured_media_square" : "square",
  "featured_media_landscape":"landscape",
  "logo":"a.png",
  "meta_information.image":"b.png"  
}

var merchant = {meta_information:{image:""}};
 
var merged = {...media_mode, ...merchant};

console.log(merged);
```

works exactly as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have Object like this  
merchant= { 
        "featured_media_square" : "square", 
        "featured_media_landscape":"landscape", 
        "logo":"a.png", 
        "meta_information": {"image":"b.png"} 
    }
You can do something like to merge . 
const newObj= { 
    ...merchant, 
    "meta_information": {"image" : "b.png"}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge `meta_information.image` with a nested object with the structure `meta_information: { image: '' }`. JavaScript cannot do that natively - you'd have to do it programmatically. If you want to merge them with using an ES5 method, the easiest method is to use `Object.assign` like you attempted, then simply delete the key you don't want.

```js
const media_mode = {
  featured_media_square: 'square',
  featured_media_landscape: 'landscape',
  logo: 'a.png',
  'meta_information.image': 'b.png'
}

const merchant = {
  meta_information: { image: 'b.png' }
}

Object.assign(merchant, media_mode);
delete merchant['meta_information.image'];
console.log(merchant);
```

Comment: where is image value?

Comment: It's there now.

Comment: you mutated the object pls try it with the object i provided

Answer (score -2):

We can use Spread Operator

```js
   var media_mode = {
        "featured_media_square" : "square",
        "featured_media_landscape":"landscape",
        "logo":"a.png",
        "meta_information.image":"b.png"  
    }

    var merchant = {meta_information:{image:""}};
    
    var merged = {...media_mode,...merchant};
    
    console.log(merged)
```

Comment: Spread Operator only does the first level.  Anything after that is NOT merged because.... javascript.